# ROKU is playing about a 1 hour delay on the live stream

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

ROKU is playing about a 1 hour delay on the live stream. It is the same feed but processing data at a much slower speed than the other platforms. Where is the problem either roku player or live stream? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be your manifest file missing the #EXT-X-ENDLIST so roku is starting at the beginning.

Workaround is to seek to a high value, like so

```
videoContent = createObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
videoContent.url = "your url"
videoContent.streamformat = "hls"
videoContent.playStart = 999999
videoContent.live = true

m.player.content = videoContent
```

If this doesn't work, you can try m.player.seek = 9999999 but it should'nt be needed

Answer (score 0):

How often is the Roku channel making a call to the feed? If it is not making calls frequently enough, that could be the source of your issue.